# OSX Language switch as in windows?

Tags: keyboard, spotlight, language, internationalization, application-switcher

How to make OSX behave the same way as Windows in regards to multiple keyboard languages (drives me crazy)?

In Windows, each app starts with default language, unless you have chosen a new language for that app.
In OSX, an app starts with the last selected language.
The problem is that when you use spotlight to launch apps it will always take the last chosen language instead of using the default one. I have to always manually switch languages it drives me crazy. Can't it work like in Windows?

I want each new app (and spotlight) to start with default language, unless I've already started that app and switched language for it.

Comment: have you turned on "switch to input source" in Keyboard settings? Also, which app is in question?

Comment: yes, every single app launches with current language, not default language

Comment: Turn that off and see if it persists

Comment: Turning it off removes the ability of having different languages per app...